# Compare values in a JSON object in a file

Tags: awk, json

I have a JSON file with thousands of JSON objects, such as below.
I want to compare the values of `st1` against `st2`.

For every object in the JSON file: If `st1` is larger than `st2`, copy that object into another file.

```json
{
    "in": 4,
    "li": [{
        "fa": 28806,
        "fs": 00002,
        "fb": 21894
    }],
    "ome": {
         "ms": "00000000000"
    },
    "st2": 1508584163,
    "ei": {
        "ev": 0
    },
    "rn": 4,
    "st1": 1508584147
}
```

I have tried using `jq`, or is it easier doing it with `awk` even though it's a JSON file?

Comment: what exactly should be copied? elaborate your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely use `jq` to parse JSON data:

```
$ cat file.json
{ "st1":0, "st2":10 }
{ "st1":0, "st2":0 }
{ "st1":10, "st2":0 }

$ jq -c 'select(.st1 > .st2)' file.json
{"st1":10,"st2":0}
```

This can be redirected into another file.